# Mac Outlook version 16 status bar disappeared

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I'm using Outlook for Mac version 16.32 on MacOS 10.15 with the "New Outlook" toggled ON in the upper right corner.

I just realized that the gray status bar at the bottom has disappeared and I don't know where to find it. That bar is critical for letting me know when my email/calendar has last been synced.

I have auto-updates on so I'm not sure if my versions changed or what. Is there a way to either 1) add the status bar back or 2) look somewhere else in Outlook for the sync status?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this status is missing?

[image]

Besides, you can confirm your version via Outlook > About Outlook. According to the Release Note, the current version is 16.30.

[image]

I’d like to recommend you [create a new profile](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-profiles-or-identities-in-outlook-for-mac-fed2a955-74df-4a24-bef6-78a426958c4c)

Comment: Yes, that's the status bar I was referring to. Looks like there was some change between minor versions 30 and 32

Comment: According to the release note, the most current version should be 16.30: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/release-notes-office-for-mac

Comment: 16.32 with the "New Outlook" enabled - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/the-new-outlook-for-mac-6283be54-e74d-434e-babb-b70cefc77439

Comment: Try create a new profile https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-profiles-or-identities-in-outlook-for-mac-fed2a955-74df-4a24-bef6-78a426958c4c